# Does interacting with things inside the area of an Alarm spell trigger it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, area-of-effect

Somebody who has cast [Alarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) is sleeping inside the area (they didn't choose the window or door option) of the spell, which is "[...] no larger than a 20-foot cube.", and the spell also states:

> Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you whenever a Tiny or larger creature touches or enters the warded area.

If I get a 10 ft pole and poke the sleeping caster gently, does the Alarm spell go off? I can see two parts to this, is the 10ft pole considered part of me as a creature? And have I entered if I've not 'set foot' inside the area? It's a little ambiguous if the 'touch' part is only intended for the door/window option.

Is it any different if I attack into it from range, with a spell or weapon?

Comment: "Area" is used to refer to the 20-foot cube, which means even if you are floating, you are still touching the area when you float into the cube (or extend a pole into it)

Comment: @Toddleson are you call me a pole? Seriously though, the floating part is the least ambiguous part. It's the 'is the pole part of me' that I think needs adressing

Comment: Yes, I would also wonder if there is a difference between a hand-held object being extended into the area and a thrown object entering the area. Do either or both count as touching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Has a tiny or larger creature entered or touched the area?

For the 10 foot pole: no, they haven’t entered it, maybe they touched it. Touch is undefined so it is a DM’s call. However, I would rule the answer is “no” because you can’t deliver a spell that has touch range with a 10 foot pole.

For a ranged attack: no, they haven’t entered it and no, they haven’t touched it.

Answer (score 7):

### It's ambiguous, so it's up to the DM.

The question quotes the entirety of the relevant part of the spell description. It doesn't define "touches" in any way, and there's a broad range of things a creature could do that would be more or less clearly "touching". For example, reaching into the area with a gloved hand to grab something is a more like "touching" than reaching in with a stick or pole. Shining a light in is not at all like "touching", but flying a *mage hand* in is. And so on.

In cases like this, the DM adjudicates. They can of course use whatever criteria they choose to make their ruling.

In the case of actions that would alert the caster by themselves, the point's moot -- being stabbed by a spear might trigger *alarm*, but even if it doesn't, it will wake you anyway.

As a DM I would typically rule that *alarm* isn't going to be fooled by this kind of stuff, and would have it go off if (non-excluded) creatures throw or poke objects into the warded area. Also bear in mind that the exact boundaries of the *alarm*, especially in its "area" mode, aren't at all easy to detect, and are certainly wholly invisible to ordinary senses. So creatures attempting to stand *just* outside and poke objects inwards are probably proceeding by guesswork.

Comment: "flying a mage hand in is" wait... what? I was going to ask this separately but I didn't as I thought it was obviously not a tiny creature.

Comment: Yes, but is the caster of the mage hand touching the area? How is that different than  reaching into the area with a gloved hand?

Comment: because it's not part of the casters 'person'?

Comment: That's an argument that could be made, the adjudication of which is up to the GM. *Mage hand* says "You can use the hand to ... open an unlocked door". Would that trigger *alarm* on that door?

Comment: I was tempted to ask that question at the same time as this one, but I decided to wait until after I had answer here. I forget if asked first, but I did post this https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194814/2788