# Does Spiritual weapon set off the Alarm spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

Related to [Does interacting with things inside the area of an Alarm spell trigger it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/194811/), still assuming [Alarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) is cast using the area option, is the caster alerted if a [Spiritual Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) is moved into the area of their Alarm spell?

The warding spell states:

> Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you whenever a Tiny or larger creature touches or enters the warded area.

As far as I can see, the spectral weapon that is evoked, is not a creature of ***any*** size. Instead it is merely a:

> [...] floating, spectral weapon [...]

And has no other relevant text, not even whether it's considered a creature or tiny.

Creatures that you 'create' that can interact with the environment seem to either have statistics, like with [Unseen Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant) (Medium size with AC and HP), or not as with [Mage Hand](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) (no given size, AC or HP).

But I have seen answers stating the weapon can act as a 'source of damage' which has confused me.

So, is the Alarm caster alerted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A spell only creates a creature if it says it does

None of the spells cited in your question say anything about creating or summoning creatures. *Mage hand* creates a "spectral, floating hand", *unseen servant* creates a "Medium force", and *spiritual weapon* creates a "floating, spectral weapon". None of these entities are ever described as creatures in the spells' texts, not even the force created by *unseen servant*. Since *alarm* is only triggered by creatures, none of these spells is capable of triggering an *alarm* spell.

Comment: That makes sense, I just know there's at least a few answers to questions here that imply the weapon is the attacker, and thus must be some sort of unspecified creature, i.e. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133787/when-attacking-with-spiritual-weapon-what-must-be-concealed-from-the-target-for

Comment: @AncientSwordRage An attacker doesn't have to be a creature. [*Bigby's hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcane-hand) creates a "force" which has hit points, AC, and can attack like a creature, but is not a creature. IIRC some traps also roll attacks when triggered.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Just to be precise, a Bigby's hand is an object in game terms, not just a "force".